# SSAS Cartesian product between dimension when no measure selected

Tags: ssas, cube, msbi

I'm testing a Multidimensional model by using Excel. Simplifying, I've two dimension tables, products and categories, and a sales fact table. There is a relationship between products and categories and between sales and products.

When I analyze this model in Excel and I put as row label products and categories, without putting the sales amount as a measure, it seems it occurs a cartesian product between product values and category values without the corresponding relationship has any effects.

This is for me an undesirable behaviour respect to the user's point of view. An user could want to navigate the structure of the model without initially to select any measures. So if a category is linked to one or more products, the selection of these two dimension tables must show the rigth data combination and not a cartesian products.

Now, how can I solve this issue, please? Thanks

Comment: Are you testing Multidimensional or Tabular data model? You mentioned both at your text.

Comment: My bad my model is a Multidimensional model ! Corrected thanks

Comment: If you run the following MDX from SSMS what measure does it return? What measure group is that measure in? Does that measure relate to the dimensions in this question? `SELECT [Measures].DefaultMember ON 0 FROM [Your Cube Name]`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider uniting *Products* and *Categories* into one dimension. As you said, *Categories* are related to *Products* itself, and facts are linked to *Products*. By uniting, you can view sales divided by *Category-Product* hierarchy, and have a tree-like view on Excel filter.

On your **[Dim Product]** add **Category** table and draw a relation between tables. Add fields from **Category** table and create hierarchy **Category - Product**. Here is [a sample](https://blog.rdx.com/creating-ssas-hierarchies-with-multiple-dimension-tables/) of similar design.

Two different dimensions should be used if objects are really independent which is not your case.